# Mypy: How to specify return and input type for builder function?

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I want to make some sort of builder function in Python with type annotation.

```py
def build_object(target_class: TargetType) -> ReturnType:
    return target_class()
```

How to correctly specify `TargetType` and `ReturnType`?
So far I have one option but I have no idea if this is correct:

```py
from typing import Type, TypeVar

TargetObjType = TypeVar("TargetObjType")

def build_object(target_class: Type[TargetObjType]) -> TargetObjType:
    return target_class()
```

I have an error from `mypy` (`error: Too many arguments for "object"  [call-arg]`) if I pass arguments into class constructor:

```py
from typing import Type, TypeVar

TargetObjType = TypeVar("TargetObjType")

def build_object(target_class: Type[TargetObjType]) -> TargetObjType:
    return target_class(1)  # mypy error
```

Is there a way to fix this without `# type: ignore`?

Comment: You'd normally just call the generic type T, to save on typing, but that generally seems OK - do you have a reason to think otherwise? Complaints from MyPy or other tooling? Given that you don't handle any args, `Callable[[], T]` would be another option for `target_class`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, thank you, still testing this approach. I was a bit confused with `typing.Generic` but now it seems clear. Thanks, I'll try and post update.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, added an update

Comment: I suppose the question is: how do you know what arguments the `target_class` is going to take? As MyPy tells you the base `object` doesn't take any, so you're going to need to be more specific about the range of things `build_object` can accept.

Comment: True, I suppose your option with `Callable[..., T]` would be more suitable. The problem with `Callable[..., T]` is that it's not very elegant type to use outside of this method and it doesn't really specify that I am expecting a `class`, not just a function that returns an object of value `T`. Which we can argue that it's basically the same thing.
But there's no way for `Type[T]` to specify that `Type` constructor can take any arguments, right?

Comment: What was the MyPy error here exactly?

Comment: Added to description. It's `error: Too many arguments for "object"  [call-arg]`